# DiffMerge integration into Tower for GIT

Tags: git, diffmerge

By chosing File -> Preferences -> Git Config -> Diff tool / Merge tool you can adjust your favourite diff/merge tool when using Tower for GIT (https://www.git-tower.com/)

DiffMerge and WinMerge are installed on my Windows machine, but only WinMerge is offered in my case.

On https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/integration/diff-tools you can read that DiffMerge should be supported, but it is obviously not. What in my setup is missing?

On https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/integration/custom-diff-tools it is described what you can do if your diff/merge tool is not directly supported by Tower. But DiffMerge should be supported. If it is not supported how would this integration script look like for DiffMerge?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like you can [set up a custom tool](https://www.git-tower.com/help/guides/integration/custom-diff-tools/windows) on git-tower, but also notice that WinMerge doesn't _really_ support three-way merge. It's only good for diffs. (They'd said so explicitly on the old WinMerge support site, but [that's apparently gone now](https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge/discussions/511).)